# why is new SimpleXMLElement($tags) causing my php script to crash;

Tags: php

I am trying to run some client code to call a server side API.
I put various put statements to see where the code crashes and the line crashing it is

```
$tagXml = new SimpleXMLElement($tags);
```

(where tags is the result of a file_get_contents call)

I downloaded php5 and I am running it from the php source file from the command line.

Why is this crashing the code.
Perhaps there is an addon for php I need to add to use new SimpleXMLElement($param)

edit I got error reporting working
Warning: simplexml_load_file(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity "https://api.domain/v2/andy/tags" in C:\java\domain-api-v2\simple\list-
tags.php on line 30
working line 30
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'String could not be pa
rsed as XML' in C:\java\domain-api-v2\simple\list-tags.php:37
Stack trace:

## 0 C:\java\domain-api-v2\simple\list-tags.php(37): SimpleXMLElement->__const

ruct('')

## 1 {main}

thrown in C:\java\domain-api-v2\simple\list-tags.php on line 37

Comment: What is the content of $tags?

Comment: Have you turned on error reporting?

Comment: You mean it actually kills the server?

Comment: may I ask how one turns on error reporting? thanks

Comment: I just used print statment as various print in the code to see where it was stopping working

Comment: *(sidenote)* `SimpleXmlElement` can load data from files when using `new SimpleXMLElement ('file.xml', 0, TRUE)` - http://de2.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.construct.php

Comment: This had been done already $tags = file_get_contents($url, false, $read_context);

Comment: The error you have posted sounds like it that the $tags variable is not valid XML

Answer (score 0):

I would check your error log. There are two immediate possibilities:

- You are not including the SimpleXMLElement class in the file that you are running
- $tags is some kind of format that SimpleXMLElement doesn't like.

If you check your error log (and have error reporting turned on) then you should see whats going on.

Comment: I added this line to my code error_reporting(E_ALL); where would I view the file with the errors listed I have php 5 for windows7 Thanks

Comment: It depends on where its set up in php.ini. Are you using WAMP or something like that? if so it will be in the WAMP folder under logs.

Comment: I am not using php on a server just through the command line, I have php installed on my c drive

Comment: Server is a misnomer. Your computer has become its own local web server. You must be running some kind of web server on your laptop like Apache to interpret the PHP.

Comment: when I was installing running the php windows installer it asked me if I wanted to installed a server and I selected no

Answer (score 0):

I was experienced this problem before. How much size of $tags contents ?

You have to use `simplexml_load_file()` instead of `file_get_contents()` , if file's size are bigger and server performance is low.